# Is it valid to to cross multiply an inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have an inequality, where one side's denominator is an expression that is always positive.  Is it valid to to perform cross multiplication on the inequality?

Example: $$\frac{X^2-16}{X+3} > 3,$$ where $X+3>0.$

Comment: Is the denominator supposed to be $x+3$ or $x$?

Comment: @politeproofs x+3. Sorry I forgot to put the brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x \in (-3,\infty)$, then $x + 3 \in (0,\infty)$, so yes we can multiply by the denominator to get $x^2 - 16 > 3(x + 3)$ without worry.